# turtlebot navigation hydro drifting orentation

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am currenting trying the autonomous navigation tutorial for turtlebot. I am having issue having it move to my goal location. While observing rviz, the turtlebot seems to have issue localizing itself properly. Even when the robot its at rest, rivz show that the turtlebot's orientation is slowly turning. Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/160561/turtlebot-navigation-hydro-drifting-orentation/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-05-06**:
Are you using create or kobuki?

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2014-05-06**:
i am using kobuki.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2014-05-06**:
Does odom topic drift?

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2014-05-06**:
I am not sure.The drifting issue seem to have disappeared though after loading another map though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kobuki gyro is factory calibrated, so no need to re-calibrate again. The problem you report is a particularity of the installed gyro that hapen rarely. It's fixed on firmware version 1.1.4, so check your robot firmware version

> rostopic echo /mobile_base/version_info

And update it if it's older. [Here](http://kobuki.yujinrobot.com/home-en/documentation/howtos/upgrading-firmware/)'s the how to.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-11**:
We observed the same problem. As a quick fix: Shutting down the drivers and turning the robot off and on solved that. (So, yes, we tried turning it off and on again!)

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2014-06-11**:
Clearly is the gyro. Update the firmware will solve it so you don't need to switch off/on nevermore.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-06-11**:
Thanks, we'll do that. I can confirm that it was the gyro. We've seen it directly in the diagnostics.

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2014-06-15**:
hi sorry for the late response. That seems to be the source of the problem, have updated the robot. Thanks